# ASP.NET vNext package restore not working

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I checked in my new vNext project into TFS at home and it was working fine.

I then went to work (corporate environment with proxy etc) and get latest. It pulled my project down and i fired up the solution.

I do a build and it's failing. The reason being that it is not restoring my nuget packages.

- I have tried editing the project.json file and it says that restore is successful upon save, it is not.
- I have tried getting new nuget packages, it says success and adds the reference but it says it is missing (exclamation mark).
- I have tried running VS 2015 as admin.
- I have tried manually creating the ..users/me/.kpm/packages folder. (this is where i believe the packages download to)
- I have tried a different proxy.

I can view the packages in nuget fine, I also get the nice intellisense in the .json file too. This makes me think it's not a proxy issue.

None of these things have worked. Any other ideas?

## Addendum

### project.json

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot"
    ],
    "packExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0.0-beta2"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: First thing to check: in VS go to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources and make sure `nuget.org` is checked. If that doesn't solve the problem, please tell me what packages are showing up with an exclamation mark and, if possible, share the `project.json` file

Comment: Nuget.org is definitely checked and set to: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ I have added my project.json too. Both of my dependencies are showing as exclamation. If it helps i sent a frowny face through visual studio with some screenshots :)

Comment: You have an extra `0` in the MVC package name. It should be `6.0.0-beta2` http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta2

Comment: That is true, must have made it wrong when i was fiddling with the config. Changing it to `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"` has not worked though unfortunately.

Comment: Can you also add the output from package restore? Output window -> Package manager log

Comment: Can you check the KRE version on the project properties, be sure that is using beta2 since you are using beta2 on all your dependencies

Comment: Yes, i see an error in the Package Manager Log. It is in fact complaining about the proxy.. `Restoring packages for C:\MyProject\Projects\ProjectEureka\project.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS'.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS
  An error occurred while sending the request.` System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. Strange as i can get packages in 2013 fine from the same source

Comment: KRE version is KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2

Comment: Try to run `kpm restore` with the `--proxy` option from console. It seems that the proxy Is the issue

Answer (score 3):

Okay i got it working, many thanks to @Victor Hurdugaci for helping me out.

Steps for me to fix this were as follows:-

- Add kpm to path, for me i found it here: `C:\Users\MyUser\.kre\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2\bin` (you might want to check your project properties to see which version you need, im not sure it matters)
- open up a cmd (make sure this was closed before adding to path)
- `cd` to your project folder (the location of your project.json)
- run `kpm restore -p http:yourproxyurl:1234` (where `yourproxyurl` is your proxy address and `1234` is your port)

At this point it did loads of downloading goodness into `C:\Users\MyUser\.kpm\packages`
I went back into Visual studio and did a build, it was still failing.

As a final step I had to open the `project.json` file and simply save it without even making any changes. At this point my references updated and all was good, it would then build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem while restoring packages when there was an unreachable server address in my nuget package sources. In that case unchecking the unreachable server in my package sources did the trick.

This behavior seems like a bug to me. It keeps failing on the one unreachable server and fails to try and restore the packages with the other, official nuget server. This also results in a failing restore of bower packages.

Answer (score 0):

I´m developing with beta8, and I had to jump a few times between beta versions and the best solutions that works for me was to add new feeds for VNext packages:

- **www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2/** This feed contains the
  release version of the packages for each milestone, for example,
  1.0.0-alpha4.
- **www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/** This feed contains the nightly dev packages with build numbers, for example,
  1.0.0-beta1-10435.

After updating the new feeds, I open and save my project file “project.json” and the references updates itself.

Take a look the next article if you need to know how to add this new feed on your Windows or *Nix machines:
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Configuring-the-feed-used-by-dnu-to-restore-packages

A very useful although general article about how dnx project in:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html